# how to store scala object onto cassandra table using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Scala model class, whose object I want to store it onto Cassandra table.there is a mismatch in the order of column names of Cassandra and Scala class variables declaration.

And there is a additional column in Cassandra table,which is not there in Scala class variables list like `(tr_tag Text)`
but i am not able to do it.

Data is not getting inserted. Please help me to resolve this.

Model scala class:

```
class THData() extends Serializable{
     var s_id: java.lang.Long = null
     var a_id: String = null
     var s_typ: String= null
     var s_dt: java.util.Date= null
     var t_s_id: String= null
     var a_s_no: String= null
     var avg_sp: java.lang.Float = null
}
```

Method to insert object into cassandra:

```
def insert(data: THData) {
     var em=sc.parallelize(Seq(data))
     em.saveToCassandra("ap", "t_s_data")
}
```

---

Cassndra table having column name like below:

sid,aid,styp,sdt,tsid,asno,avgsp,tr_tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the column names as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/4_mapper.md):

[image]